# How to change the windows drive for JupyterLab in Anaconda Navigator?

Tags: windows, anaconda, jupyter

Under Windows, JupyterLab does not allow navigation in the UI to any drive other than the drive that JupyterLab was started in. By default this is the C: drive.

How can you access notebooks on another drive?

Answer (score 4):

Anaconda does not allow switching between drives but you can start Jupyter Lab or a Jupyter notebook on another drive, for example the D: drive.

- First shutdown any running JupyterLab, then
- Open a terminal window from within Anaconda Navigator. To do this, select **environments** in the Navigator window and then click the **green "play" arrow next to base(root)** -- or which ever environment you are using.
- then in the terminal window type

`jupyter notebook --generate-config`

- this will generate a file in your user directory under `.jupyter\jupyter_notebook_config.py`
- edit the file.
- Set the variable `c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir` to whatever directory you want to start in, for example

`c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = "D:\mydir"`

- *NOTE do not put a trailing backslash. Also if the directory pathname contains spaces ensure you are using double quotes.*
- save the file and test that all is working. In the command line type

`jupyter lab`

- this should start JupyterLab correctly, check for any errors in the terminal window. JupyterLab should start in the directory you set in the file.
- If all is well, shutdown JupyterLab and run it from the Anaconda Navigator window as usual. All should work now.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by GreyMS in this [github issue](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1334), you can use an mklink:

```
mklink /D D_Drive D:\sources
```